# clojure - take-while to include last item when predicate is false

Tags: clojure

I have the following function that uses `take-while`

```
(defn process [[cash amount wrappers]]
  (let [bought (int (Math/floor (/ cash amount)))
        free (->>
              (iterate (partial unwrapper wrappers) bought)
              (take-while (partial (fn [w a]
                                     (prn (str "a = " a))
                                     (>= a w)
                                     ) wrappers)))]
```

The problem I have is that I want to include the last item when the predicate is false but `take-while` does not return that last item.

Is there a way round that with `take-while` or should I use something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this, based on the source of `take-while`:

```
(defn take-while+
  [pred coll]
  (lazy-seq
    (when-let [[f & r] (seq coll)]
      (if (pred f)
        (cons f (take-while+ pred r))
        [f]))))
```

Comment: Can you tell me why you cloned my answer?

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin I didn't clone your answer, I stopped reading it at "you might want to write a custom take-while." I then looked at the source of take-while, simplified it and added the vector at the end instead of returning nil.

Answer (score 3):

The common approach is to use `split-with`, which returns the results of both `take-while` and `drop-while` in a vector. You can then append the first element of the `drop-while` result.

It requires two passes, though. You might want to write a custom take-while...

```
(defn take-while-and-one
  [pred coll]
  (lazy-seq
   (when-let [s (seq coll)]
     (if (pred (first s))
       (cons (first s) (take-while-and-one pred (rest s)))
       (list (first s))))))
```

Comment: You could also use `partition-by` and take the first seq plus the first member of the second. Just one pass there.

Comment: Thats a great idea. You should post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Had a bit of a try at that `partition-by` approach I mentioned in my comment to [Leon Grapenthin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30921452/1571406). It generally works out OK, but it turns out when you consume one of the partitions made by it, `partition-by` eagerly evaluates the next partition. So while this should be a lazy approach, it's less lazy than his solution and consequently can't handle the edge case of an infinite sequence where the predicate mapping looks like `(true true ... true false false....)` Still, fun problem to experiment on.

```
(defn take-while-plus-n 
  "Lazily returns successive items from coll while (pred item) returns true,
  then an additional n items. pred must partition coll into segments of finite length."
  [pred n coll]
  (if (pred (first coll))
    (let[[head & tails] (partition-by pred coll)]
      (lazy-cat head (->> tails flatten (take n))))
    (take n coll)))
```

I threw the variable number of "additional items" on mainly because I ended up using `take` in both cases.

Comment: You are right, I didn't see partition-by uses count, which btw. would also count as a second pass...

Comment: Ah, so it does. It always seems to be those little details that trip you up when you want to go maximally lazy.

Comment: Still think that you are on the right way: http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1764  :)

Answer (score 0):

I would first create a vector of the predicate results and then process that as desired:

```
(def xx (range 10))
;=> (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
(defn my-tst [arg]
  (< arg 5))
(def flags (mapv my-tst xx))
;=> [true true true true true false false false false false]
(def num-true (count (filter identity flags)))
num-true ;=> 5
(def num-keep (inc num-true))
num-keep ;=> 6
(def keepers (take num-keep xx))
keepers 
;=> (0 1 2 3 4 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the transducer version:

```
(defn take-while+
  ([pred]
   (fn [rf]
     (fn
       ([] (rf))
       ([result] (rf result))
       ([result input]
        (if (pred input)
          (rf result input)
          (reduced (conj! result input))))))))
```